# X-UA-Compatible tag to use latest version of browser engine for IE7-IE9, but use IE9 for IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, compatibility, internet-explorer-10

I have a website which hasn't been tested in IE10 yet. Therefore I want IE10 to run it in IE9 mode, which worked with the X-UI-Compatible tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

Only problem: IE8 and IE7 are unable to interpret this value and show the "compatibility-button".

What I would like to achieve is that IE10 renders my site in IE9 mode, IE7 should run the site as IE7, IE8 should run it as IE8 and IE9 should run it as IE9 and the "compatibility-button" should not be visible.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: Making code work in IE is like adjusting rabbit ear antennas for a TV.

Answer (score 1):

Render the meta tag according to user agent. This requires server processing -> cannot be achieved on client.